# Need help with three visual studio errors - C++ errors occuring when trying to build solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I get the following errors when I try to build this project:

```
error C2182: 'read_data':illegal use of type 'void'
error C2078: too many initializers
errors c2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::ofstream' to int
```

All of the above seem to be pointing to my function call on line 72, which is this line: 
void read_data(finput, foutput);

I've looked up these error codes on the MSDN site but wasn't able to use the description to deduce what might be wrong.

Any ideas/tips are appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void read_data(ifstream& finput, ofstream& foutput);
//PRE: The address of the ifstream & ofstream objects is passed to the function
//POST: The data values are read in until the end of the file is reached

void print_data(ofstream& foutput, string fname, string lname, int largest, int smallest);
//PRE: The address of the ofstream object and the values of fname, lname and largest and smallest integer
//     in each row is passed to the function
//POST: The values are outpur to the file with formatting

int max(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4);
//PRE: Four integer values are passed to the function
//POST: The largest of the four integer values is returned

int min(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4);
//PRE: Four integer values are passed to the function
//POST: The smallest of the four integer values is returned

int main()
{
    //Declare the filestream objects
    ifstream finput;
    ofstream foutput;

    //Attempt to open the input & output files
    //In each case, print an error message and quit if they fail to open
    finput.open("program4_input.txt");
    if (finput.fail())
    {
        cout <<"The input file failed to open!" << endl;
        return exit(1);
    }

    foutput.open("output.txt");
    if (foutput.fail())
    {
        cout <<"The output file failed to open!" << endl;
        return exit(2);
    }

    void read_data(finput, foutput);

    return 0;
}


//Function definitions
void read_data(ifstream& finput, ofstream& foutput)
{
    string fname, lname;
    int num1, num2, num3, num4, largest, smallest;

    while(finput >> fname)
    {
        finput  >> lname >> num1 >> num2 >> num3 >> num4;
        largest = max(num1, num2, num3, num4);
        smallest = min(num1, num2, num3, num4);

        print_data(foutput, fname, lname, largest, smallest);


    }

}

void print_data(ofstream& foutput, string fname, string lname, int largest, int smallest)
{
    foutput << setw(15) << fname << setw(15) << lname << setw(10) << largest << setw(10) << smallest 
            << endl;
}

int max(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    int lnum, lnum1, lnum2;

    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        lnum1 = num1;
    }
    else
        lnum1 = num2;


    if (num3 > num4)
    {
        lnum2 = num3;
    }
    else
        lnum2 = num4;


    if (lnum1 > lnum2)
    {
        lnum = lnum1;
    }
    else
        lnum = lnum2;

    return lnum;
}


int min(int num1, int num2, int num3, int num4)
{
    int snum, snum1, snum2;

    if (num1 < num2)
    {
        snum1 = num1;
    }
    else
        snum1 = num2;


    if (num3 > num4)
    {
        snum2 = num3;
    }
    else
        snum2 = num4;


    if (snum1 > snum2)
    {
        snum = snum1;
    }
    else
        snum = snum2;

    return snum;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the problem is the line

```
void read_data(finput, foutput);
```

inside the main function.
Don't specify the return type when *calling* the function. Only when declaring it. In other words, the line should just read

```
read_data(finput, foutput);
```

Comment: arrghhh i see i. I cant believe I stared at it for 30 minutes and didnt event see that. Boy do I feel stupid. Thank you!

Comment: obijuan, if this is the solution, you should accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have void before your call which is the signature of the function - you are not actually calling it which is why the compiler is complaining.

Comment: Thank you maggie. Boy, do I feel dumb.

Comment: Don't feel dumb - it is so easy to miss mistakes - better to ask then spin your wheels:)